# What is a concise syntax for accessing the other element of two element collection?

Tags: c++, syntax, stl

I have a 2-element collection `{a, b}` and a complex expression `ex(_, _)` involving both elements in non-commutative way. The result of computation I'm looking for is equivalent to:

```
ex(a, b);
ex(b, a);
```

but instead of repeating the whole expression twice (defining a function computing `ex` is not acceptable), I would like to use a loop like this:

```
for (auto i: {a, b})
  ex(i, <other element>);
```

What is a short way of writing such a loop?

**EDIT**

Since number of readers found my question unclear, please have a look at two answers below, which present solutions I was looking for. `ex(a, b)` is a shorthand for a long chunk of code using `a` and `b` in that order. Reasons why I don't want to define a function `ex` are mainly stylistic and beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this is directly without the for loop.

Comment: How is that for loop any better than the two calls to `ex`? Or a function taking two arguments that calls `ex` twice?

Comment: Why dont you use a pair for your container ? Access each element with `.first` and `.second` ?

Comment: "defining a function computing ex is not acceptable" - why not? Also, can you provide some actual code? It's hard to grok what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Praetorian `ex` is 20 lines of code, so `ex` repeated twice is 40 lines of code vs. a loop of about 21 lines of code. Function is not acceptable because too much of local context would have to be passed as parameters.

Comment: Ehm write a single function that calls `ex` twice? Use a lambda or a functor to capture context.

Comment: @quantdev The problem is, if `i` is one of pair's elements, what is a simple way to access the other one?

Comment: @PaulJurczak So write a lambda that captures the context variables implicitly. There's no *simple* solution to what you want, and anything you come up with will be a lot more complicated than a function call.

Comment: @Praetorian That's what I was afraid of, but I wanted to make sure that I'm not missing a simple trick.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Perhaps the answer I just posted below will clarify what I'm trying to get.

Comment: If defining `ex` as a function worries you about performance, just make it inline.

Comment: It sounds like you have larger design issues than what is illustrated here. If you think you need to pass in too many variables for the context, then you need to completely rethink your design.

Answer (score 1):

If the elements are always to be indexed 0 and 1 (such as in a vector v) then you could use exclusive or `^` to select the alternative index:

```
for(auto i: {0, 1})
    ex(v[i], v[i ^ 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
for (auto i: {false, true})
  ex(i ? a : b, i ? b : a);
```

and another one:

```
vector<int> v = {a, b};

do {
    ex(v[0], v[1]);
} while(next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
```

or:

```
vector<int> v = {a, b};

for (auto i: {0, 1})
  ex(v[i], v[(i+1)%2]);
```